Would it be possible to solve an linear programming problem with quantum computing, obtaining the same result as in an solver
So, I've begun viewing quantum computing out of curiosity and I have been studying linear programming in my university. I have heard that quantum computing can do linear programming equations, and I would like to make the following question, is it possible to resolve the following problem:
max Z = x1 + 2x2 + 3x3
s.t.
x1 + x2 + x3 <= 60
x1 + 2x2 + 2x3 <= 110
x1 + x2 + 2x3 <= 90
x1, x2, x3 >= 0

While reaching the same results, or somewhat close to which I would get in an solver like Lindow or AMPL?
I did use Lindow to resolve the problem and I do know that Solvers are superior in everyway to what a quantum computer and its algorithms can perform in the matter of linear programming nowadays, but it still indulges me if it really isn't possible to reach the same results.

You could probably be able to reach the same result provided quantum computers are more matured technology. However, D-Wave is really close to a marketable device, so you can try so solve with their Leap environment. Just note, LP problems can be usually solved in polynomial time (in worst case unfortunately, simplex algorithm is exp. complex). So, I see a little benefit of QC for LP. On the other hand, QC can be very useful for binary, discrete or mixed programming.

Yes. Check this guide https://docs.classiq.io/latest/explore/applications/optimization/integer_linear_programming/integer_linear_programming/
